# GetBytes method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am using `LINQ` to select a list based on a particular condition. The attribute value is stored in `byte array`, which is later encrypted while storing in the database table. I want to using this attribute in my `SELECT LINQ` query now, but it is throwing the following exception when I try to:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Byte[] GetBytes(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

This is the code that I using:

```
var result = (from history in context.Histories
                              where history.ID == Id & 
                              (history.Salary != null || history.Salary != Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0"))
                              select (DateTime?)history.Date).Max();
                return result;
```

I want to select the date from the history table, of those id's whose salary is either not equal to null or 0. How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the bytes first :

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0");

var result = (from history in context.Histories
                              where history.ID == Id & 
                          (history.Salary != null || history.Salary != bytes)
                          select (DateTime?)history.Date).Max();
            return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0");
var result = (from history in context.Histories
                          where history.ID == Id & 
                          (history.Salary != null || history.Salary != bytes)
                          select (DateTime?)history.Date).Max();
            return result;
```

LINQ can't evaluate your GetBytes when it translates your query to SQL